# Generate code as Windows Forms do with .designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I think I have a big problem.

I have a two projects solution.

First one is UI project.
Second one in an Algorithms Service.

I need to **generate** (or overwrite) a class (fileUI.cs) in UI part **just before compiling** it.

The main idea is that when you edit a class in de Services part (fileSA.cs) and you build the solution just a moment before the class in the UI part (fileUI.cs) is updated with Services part class information (fileSA.cs), and then, compiled.

I think its similar what VS does with the .designer.cs of every form(user control...)

I dont know if its possible...

Thanks a lot

Comment: See: [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: I found interesting this website for any other with the same problem.
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15728/Write-your-own-Code-Generator-or-Template-Engine-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need T4 Template Here

> [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio has a mechanism called **single-file generators** / **custom tools** that targets exactly this use case: generating a file (`fileUI.cs` in your case) when another file has changed (`fileSA.cs`).

Refer to the MSDN article [*Implementing Single-File Generators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx) to learn how such a custom file generator is written.

P.S.: While this would be the appropriate mechanism, I don't think that it will work across the project boundary.

Comment: +1 for using the extension points in VS for what they are meant. (but sadly my COM skillz be rusty)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom msbuild target in your project (right click on project -> edit project file). See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462) for more info about msbuild targets. You can run custom tasks as part of this target. A way to generate code is using T4 templates. More info [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/) on running t4 templates as part of the build process. Oleg Sych has a lot of detailed explanations on T4 and is kind of the authority on the matter, so his [site](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) is a good read to start.